# Can't pass a VAR into PDO SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

for some reason I can't pass a VAR into a PDO SQL query .

```
<?php
$hostname = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";

$score = "B" ;





try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname='DBNAME'", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected to database"; // check for connection
    $dbh->exec("UPDATE Quiz1 SET '$score' = 1 WHERE Question = 1");  // THIS DOES NOT  
    //$dbh->exec("UPDATE Quiz1 SET B = 1 WHERE Question = 1"); // THIS WORKS
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dbh->exec("UPDATE Quiz1 SET `$score` = 1 WHERE Question = 1");
```

If you have to quote your table or column names for some reason then you have to use ` in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `$score` variable here as an attribute name and attribute names should not be in quotes. Try this:

```
$dbh->exec("UPDATE Quiz1 SET $score = 1 WHERE Question = 1");
```

(I haven't tested.)